# Should I tell Intellij that my WSL filesystem is case sensitive?

Tags: intellij-idea, filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I share my Windows 10 filesystem with the Windows Subsystem for Linux.  I keep my coding projects in the `dev` folder in my user directory, and share that to `/mnt/c/Users/Conan/dev` in WSL.  Intellij runs projects from the Windows filesystem, but I use a range of command-line tools to run things (such as `java`) from the share in WSL.

When I start Intellij it says:

> Filesystem Case-Sensitivity Mismatch
>   The project seems to be located on a case-sensitive file system.
>   This does not match the IDE setting (controlled by property "idea.case.sensitive.fs")

Is this correct?  My Windows filesystem is not case-sensitive, but the files were created from bash in WSL.  Which setting should I use?

Comment: Currently IDE can not handle mixed file system paths in projects: [IDEA-135546](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135546). Try making directory as case-insensitive as [suggested here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200127#focus=streamItem-27-3088427-0-0)

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, I'll vote for/follow that issue and hope for a resolution.  Setting the property just gives me the opposite error.

Answer (score 5):

Better solution than making the Linux directory case-insensitive. Make the Windows directory you are using case-sensitive. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/02/28/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/

This makes for a more complete Linux experience and avoids interop issues such as described here.

In addition, I recommend utilizing the metadata option available in build 17134 (April Update or 1803) or newer for Windows via wsl.conf (manually create in /etc). This will allow your windows directories to keep the permissions assigned by the linux distro you're running with WSL. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/02/07/automatically-configuring-wsl/