# Filesystem Case Sensitivity Mismatch (Android Studio, Windows 10)

Tags: android, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Android Studio in Windows 10. After upgrading a hard drive (containing projects and the Android SDK) I came across the following warning which struck me as odd, because windows files are meant to be case insensitive (although NTFS supports case sensitivity)

### [image: Case sensitivity warning]

ADB seems to be broken also:

### [image: ADB error]

Android Studio shows the warning because it detects a case sensitive filesystem, when the operating system it is running on is supposed to be case insensitive - but why are the files being treated as case sensitive on windows?

Answer (score 0):

The files had been copied to the new drive using rsync running on the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Windows 10 has introduced support for case sensitive filenames in April 2018: 
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-ntfs-treat-folders-case-sensitive-windows-10

It turns out that that rsync copied the files and set the case sensitive attribute to enabled.

I re-copied all the files over to the new drive in windows and everything now works as expected

Comment: other than system installed drive will slow down interactions

Answer (score 0):

Linux by default uses case-sensitivity therefore WSL is case-sensitive. This is duplicate of [Should I tell Intellij that my WSL filesystem is case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52852105/should-i-tell-intellij-that-my-wsl-filesystem-is-case-sensitive/53015160#53015160) in which I provided the solution.